# I'm syncing application details from external database with an api call, getting error none type has no attribute strip

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def get_applications(token):
    """ Get applications from eInsight """
    url = '{0}/tip/rest/v1/model/Application'.format(TROUX_URL)

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
    }

    qsargs = {
        'select': '*',
        'limit': 1000,
    }

    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, params=qsargs, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()

        for app in data['model']:
            yield app

        if '_next' in data:
            url = data['_next']['model']['nextUrl']
            qsargs = None

        else:
            return
def update_application(token, eapp):
    """ Use data from eInsight to update applications in camp-backend """
    app = Application.objects.filter(attributes__application_uuid__iexact=eapp['_id'])

    eapp_name = eapp['name'].strip()

def sync_applications():
    """ Main Function to sync applications from eInsight """
    token = get_token()

    futures = list()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for app in get_applications(token):
            # future = executor.submit(update_application, app)
            # futures.append(future)
            update_application(token, app)
```

Comment: If you're using an IDE, please put a break-point at line containing `eapp_name = eapp['name'].strip()` or just wirte `print(eapp)`. Can you please update the question with output you got. 

If I'm not wrong 'name' key doesn't correspond to a value or may be the value is being lost during the process of object being fetched from json.

Comment: I tried printing eapp, it prints the details of data but in between a None object is returned, while printing eapp['name], same application name is being printed but in between None object is printed earlier it was working fine but from past few days issue is happening

Comment: Can you please add the output that you got when you tried `print(eapp)` and `print(eapp['name'])` to the question by editing it.

Comment: I have got the solution have put the function call of updating application in try and catch and it did worked.

Comment: That's great. Can you answer the question yourself and close this.

Comment: def sync_applications():

    """ Main Function to sync applications from eInsight """

    token = get_token()



    futures = list()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

        for app in get_applications(token):

            # future = executor.submit(update_application, app)

            # futures.append(future)

            try:

                update_application(token, app)

            except Exception as e:

                print('ERROR: ' + app['_id'])

                print(e)

adding function call in try and catch block solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sync_applications(): 
""" Main Function to sync applications """
    token = get_token() 
    futures = list() 
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor: 
        for app in get_applications(token):
            #future = executor.submit(update_application, app)
            #futures.append(future) 
            try: 
                update_application(token, app) 
            except Exception as e: 
                print('ERROR: ' + app['_id'])
                print(e)
```

adding function call in try and catch block solved it.